# How can I treat many log files as one virtual file in Perl?

Tags: perl, filehandle

I've got multiple access logs in the logs directory, following the naming convention below:

```
access.log.1284642120
access.log.1284687600
access.log.1284843260
```

Basically, the logs are "rotated" by Apache per day, so they can be sorted in order.

I am trying to "read them one after another", so that they can be treated as one log file.

```
my @logs = glob('logs/access.log.*');
```

The above code will glob all the logs, but I am not sure:

- In which order will the logs be organized, alphabetically?
- if I want to check "the latest access time from an unique IP", how could I do this?

I have a Perl script that can read a single access log and check this easily (my algorithm is to have a big hash which uses IP address as the key and the access time as the value, and just keep pushing key/value pairs to it...). 
But I don't want to just merge all access files into one temporary file just for this process.

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to ensure a particular order, sort it yourself, even if just to assure yourself that it will come out right:

```
 my @files = sort { ... } glob( ... );
```

In this case, where the filenames are all the same except for the particular digits, you might not need the sort block:

```
 my @files = sort glob( ... );
```

To read them as one über-file, I like to use a `local @ARGV` so I can use the diamond operator, which is really just the magic `ARGV` filehandle. When it gets to the end of one file in `@ARGV`, it moves on to the next. This fakes specifying all the files on the command line by assigning to `@ARGV` inside the program:

```
 {
 local @ARGV = sort { ... } glob( ... );

 while( <> ) {
      ...;
      }
 }
```

If you need to know the file you are currently processing, look in `$ARGV`.

If you need something more fancy, you might have to resort to brute force.

Comment: +1 for punctuation. Like metal bands, SO answers are better with umlauts.

Comment: You also get the magic of `$.` keeping track of the current line number of the current file.

Answer (score 2):

In a Unix-y environment, you can leverage the shell to group your files together:

```
my @files = glob("$dir/access.log.*");
open my $one_big_logfile, "-|", "cat @files" or die ...;
while (<$one_big_logfile>) {
   ...
}
```